# Node.js calling a function from script to update UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, websocket

Here is my webserver:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('hello\n');
    socket.write('world\n');

    //RECEIVE PACKET ON SOCKET
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        //socket.write(data);
        //console.log(data);
        testSocketData(data)
    });
    
});

server.listen(8000);
```

And the method `testSocketData(data)` is located in file `update_ui.js` and does the following:

```
function testSocketData(test) {
    $('#p1').text(test)
}
```

Where `#p1` refers to the id of a paragraph element in my `main.html`. I know that my socket is working, however I get:

`ReferenceError: testSocketData is not defined.`

How can I simply pass off the data received from my node.js server to the rest of my web application?

Answer (score 2):

You must move that method(with socket.on('data') as well) from the server to the client side. When you receive a message via socket, the p1 element will update its text too.

On the server you will still need to have a socket.on('data') to receive the messages from the client.

**Edit:**
Here is some code, a little bit changed from my comment below.
On server:

```
function computeSomeResults(data) {
// your logic here
}
socket.on('servermsg', function(data) {
  var result = computeSomeResults(data);
  socket.emit('clientmsg', result);
});
```

On client:

```
function testSocketData(test) {
    $('#p1').text(test);
}
socket.on('clientmsg', function(data) {
  testSocketData(data);
  // emit something maybe?
}
```

Eventually, you may want to send something to the server:

```
$('#p1').on('click', function(){
  socket.emit('servermsg', $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I don't understand - should I move all the webserver code to my `update_ui.js` script and then run `node update_ui.js` instead of `node webserver.js`? Or put the UI updating function in the `webserver.js` script? New node.js user here.

Comment: You don't have access to the methods on client side from your server. From the server you must send the data, the text you want. That's all! On the client-side, you must listen to the data and apply the testSocketData method. That's why I have said you have to move it from server to client side and provide a mechanism to listen and send data in your server.

Comment: `That's why I have said you have to move it from server to client side and provide a mechanism to listen and send data in your server.` So how do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://socket.io/. They have on the server a `socket.on('my other event')`, you must have a similar listener, `socket.on('data', function(data) { var result = /* perform some computation with the data received.*/ socket.emit('data', result) });`

Now, look at the client side, they have a socket.on('news'). You will need on the client side the testSocketData declaration and socket.on('data', function(data){ testSocketData(data); });

Emit and on must match, if you have socket.emit('evt1', someData); on server side, you must have socket.on('evt1', function(data){}) on client side.

Comment: Sounds good, could you add the relevant code to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37267/discussion-between-silviu-burcea-and-jds)